# NodeJs, VueJs post return 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

I use vue,vue-route,nodejs.
What i need ? send the form data to existing json file. Maybe there is a better possibility than post?

At this moment i try post request but i have a problem:

In my router :

```
export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'test',
        component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
        path:'/add',
        name: 'add',
        component: Test
    }
]})
```

In my component HelloWorld.vue :

```
  axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/add',
                data: {
                    name: this.config.persons.name,
                    phone: this.config.persons.phone,
                    email: this.config.persons.email
                }
            });
```

POST method return:

> POST http://localhost:8080/add 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This error is from the backend. Add the backend code. so that we can understand

Comment: Vue-router is client side, you say `this.$router.push('/add')` to change the path. It has no use for background requests. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Frax i want to save my data form to json file 
var jsonData = require('./../../persons.json');
 jsonData.persons.push(this.$data.list);
(here save to file)

Comment: You need a server to write to a file on server. And it seems like you should be using a database, not a standalone JSON file. Try to learn some basics about writing web applications in Node. [Express](https://expressjs.com/) may be a good starting point, as it is very simple, but it's far from being only option.